# Syntax wrong in sort script?

Tags: google-apps-script

Writing a script to sort a sheet by a range , A4 to the bottom right cell (because rows and/or columns may be added).  The script finds the  cell of the last column/last row and then uses that in the range var.  Problem is when I try to run this script it gives me "Missing ) after argument list. (line 8, file "Sort By Gamer Tag")".  But I've closed all the "(".

Any advice?

Thanks

```
function sortByGamerTag() {

  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sht=ss.getSheetByName('Master Summary 2');
  var lastRow=sht.getLastRow();
  var lastCol=sht.getLastColumn();
  var lastCell=sht.getCell(lastCol,lastRow);
  var range = sht.getRange("A4":lastCell);
  range.sort(2);

}
```

﻿

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there are 2 modification points in your script. Please confirm below.

### Modification points :

1. `range` of `getRange(range)` can be given by strings.

   - So please change from `"A4":lastCell` to `"A4:" + lastCell`.
2. `getCell()` returns a given cell within a range. [(Ref.)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getCell(Integer,Integer)) In your script, an error occurs at `var lastCell=sht.getCell(lastCol,lastRow);`.

   - So please change from `var lastCell=sht.getCell(lastCol,lastRow);` to `var lastCell = sht.getRange(lastRow, lastCol).getA1Notation();`.

### Modified script :

Your script can be written by modifying above points as follows.

```
function sortByGamerTag() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sht=ss.getSheetByName('Master Summary 2');
  var lastRow=sht.getLastRow();
  var lastCol=sht.getLastColumn();
  var lastCell = sht.getRange(lastRow, lastCol).getA1Notation();
  var range = sht.getRange("A4:" + lastCell);
  range.sort(2);
}
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: no you understood perfectly. Thank you for explaining.  I had not thought at all about the A1 Notation.   Thank you.

Comment: Welcome. Thank you, too.